# Flutter: Downloading Network Image before showing it

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I want to show banner images in a `CarouselSlider.builder`. When I use the widget `NetworkImage`, the images are downloaded and shown, so, it takes time to show them. I used `CachedNetworkImage`, I can put a placeholder now, but I do not want to put a placeholder. What I want to do is to load the images to cache, before the their turn comes in the `CarouselSlider`. For example, while the first image in my list is shown, I want to download the second image to local. So, I am going to be able to show the banner images without a delay. Is there any way to do it in flutter? I think it should be, because in the second circle of the loop in the `CarouselSlider.builder` the images are shown without delay.

This is my current code:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: viewModel.bannerImages[index],
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              placeholder: (context, url) => new Container(
                color: Palette.lightGrey,
              ),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Container(
                color: Palette.lightGrey,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To preload images before they are shown in the CarouselSlider, you can use the precacheImage method provided by Flutter's ImageProvider class. This method allows you to load images into the cache before displaying them, reducing the delay when showing images in the CarouselSlider.

Here's how you can preload images using precacheImage:

1-Import the necessary packages:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
```

2-Create a list to store the preloaded images:

```
List<ImageProvider> _preloadedImages = [];
```

3-Use the precacheImage method to load images into the cache before they are displayed in the CarouselSlider:

```
CarouselSlider.builder(
  itemCount: viewModel.bannerImages.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
    // Check if the image is already preloaded, if not, preload it.
    if (_preloadedImages.length <= index) {
      _precacheImage(viewModel.bannerImages[index]);
    }

    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: viewModel.bannerImages[index],
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
        // If the image is preloaded, use it directly from the cache.
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: imageProvider,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      placeholder: (context, url) => Container(
        color: Palette.lightGrey,
      ),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
        color: Palette.lightGrey,
      ),
    );
  },
  options: CarouselOptions(
    // Your carousel options here
  ),
),
```

4-Define the _precacheImage method to preload images:

```
void _precacheImage(String imageUrl) {
  final imageProvider = CachedNetworkImageProvider(imageUrl);
  precacheImage(imageProvider, context);
  _preloadedImages.add(imageProvider);
}
```

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT